# how to read a line from stdin again after reading something from stdin in C?

Tags: c, stdin, readline, fgets

This program runs fine.

```c
int main()
{
    {
        printf("Type something:\n");
        char* message = malloc(64 * sizeof(char));
        fgets(message, 64, stdin);
        printf("message ist : %s\n", message);
        free(message);
    }
}
```

But when i run the following program, It doesnt let me write anything, it prints "message ist: "

```c
int main()
{
    char action;

    while(action!='e')
    {
        printf("print a line: p\n");
        printf("End Program:  e\n");

        action = getc(stdin);

        if(action == 'p')
        {
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("Type something:\n");
            char* message = malloc(64 * sizeof(char));
            fgets(message, 64, stdin);
            printf("message ist : %s\n", message);
            free(message);
        }
        else if(action == 'e')
        {
            printf(" Program ended successfully\n");
            exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have explaination why it let me input in first program,
and why it didn't let me input in second program?

I tried to flush the keyboard inputs, it didn't work.
I tried with `getline()` instead of `fgets()`, same result.

I would be thankful for any ideas and explaination.

Comment: Now it's time to start debugging. Have investigated the value of `action`? And, btw, `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior.

Comment: when you type "p" you realy type "p<ENTER>". That "<ENTER>" is the only character that `fgets()` sees.

Comment: You may want to initialize `action` rather than comparing it to an unknown value: `char action = 0;`

Comment: @klutt: `fflush(stdin);` is indeed UB on implementations without extensions. The Windows library, for example, extends C by (possibly among other things) defining `fflush(stdin);`. I never use it though, and I think relying needlessly on an extension is bad.

Comment: @pmg If they know that they are using an extension, then they can ignore such advices. If they don't well, then it's a good thing to tell them. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like `fflush(stdin)` (it is undefined as already mentioned) does not work properly. The problem is the `'\n'` which is still in the buffer and has to be removed. Otherwise `fgets` is called, finds the `'\n'` in the buffer (which marks the end of the input) and continues with the program.

Try this instead:

```
    // fflush(stdin);
    while (getchar() != '\n');
    printf("Type something:\n");
    char* message = (char*) malloc(64 * sizeof(char));
    fgets(message, 64, stdin);
    printf("message is : %s\n", message);
    free(message);
```

What also works fine (but probably unintended) is an input like "p MyMessage". This prints the message indeed.

Answer (score 1):

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void customFlush()
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
}

int main()
{
    char action;
    char message[64] = { };

    while(action != 'e')
    {
        printf("---------\nCommands:\n'p' for print a line\n'e' for end program\n\nType a command: ");
        action = getc(stdin);
        // Exclude unnecessary chars (<Enter> and so on)
        customFlush(); // or fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END);

        if (action == 'p')
        {
            memset(message, 0, sizeof(message));
            printf("\nType something:\t");
            fgets(message, 64, stdin);
            printf("\nTyped message:\t%s\n", message);
            // Here is also possible place for calling customFlush or fseek()
        }
    }
    printf("Program ended successfully\n");
}
```